# Polynomial program not working as expected

Tags: java

So I Created a class Term. This class represents a term of a polynomial such as 2x4 where 2 is coefficient and 4 is exponent of the
 term.

Data members:-
int coefficient
int exponent

```
public class Term2 {

    private int coefficient;
    private int exponent;

    public Term2() {
        coefficient = 0;
        exponent = 0;
    }


    public Term2(int coefficient, int exponent) {
        this.coefficient = coefficient;
        this.exponent = exponent;
    }


    public int getCoefficient() {
        return coefficient;
    }

    public void setCoefficient(int coefficient) {
        this.coefficient = coefficient;
    }

    public int getExponent() {
        return exponent;
    }

    public void setExponent(int exponent) {
        this.exponent = exponent;
    }

}
```

then I Created another class called Polynomial. The internal representation of a polynomial is an array of Terms. The size of this array should be fixed. I 
Provided a constructor for this class that will set all terms of a polynomial object as zero (where coefficient is 0 and exponent is 0).

then I created a funtion called 
setTerm(int, int) 
which Setting a term of a polynomial object. Each successive call of 
this function should set next term of the polynomial object.

```
package javaapplication2;



import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polynomials {

    private Term2 terms[];
    private int valueLength = 0;

    public Polynomials(int termSize) {
        terms = new Term2[termSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
            terms[i] = new Term2(0, 0);
        }
    }

    public void setTerm(int c, int e) {
        if (valueLength >= terms.length) {
            System.out.println("big");
            return;
        }

        terms[valueLength++] = new Term2(c, e);

        if (e > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
                terms[i] = new Term2(c, e);

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of terms : ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();

        Polynomials p = new Polynomials(n);

        p.setTerm(2, 3);
        Term2 t = new Term2();

    }

}
```

**STUCKED**

is the code structure is correct as I am not able to get the expected output in addtion i also want to achieve the two below funtionality

1.sort() ñ to arrange the terms in ascending order of exponents.

2. Provide a function to print a polynomial object

please suggest me the best solution

**OUTPUT**

```
run:
Enter the number of terms : 
2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: Why not simply represent your polynomial as an integer array, where each index indicates the exponent and the size of that array is its degree? `int polynomial[] {7,0,0,2}` means 2x^3 + 7.

Comment: To print it: `for(int i=0;i<polynomial.length;i++)System.out.print("("+polynomial[i]+")x^"+i+"+");`

Comment: Hey can you show your implementation in my code

Comment: It makes no sense to allow multiple "terms" with the same exponent. It also makes no sense to overwrite each and every existing term in a loop whenever a call to setTerm is made. I would suggest solving some simpler exercises first, you seem to have an uncertain understanding of the basics such as arrays and loops.

Answer (score 1):

The arrray is a too complicated data structure here. (Besides `if (e > 0) { ... }` messes things up.)

Either a Map from exponent to Term2 or to the coefficient.

```
public class Polynomials {

    private SortedMap<Integer, Term2> termsByExponent = new TreeMap<>();

    public Polynomials() {
    }

    public void setTerm(int c, int e) {
        termsByExponent.put(e, new Term2(c, e));
    }

    /**
     * @param exp the exponent (not the index).
     */
    public Term2 getTerm(int exp) {
        return termsByExponent.computeIfAbsent(exp, e -> new Term2(0, e));
    }

    public Term2 getTermByIndex(int i) {
        return termsByExponent.values().get(i);
    }

    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return termsByExponent.values().stream()
            .map(t -> String.format("%s%d.x^%d",
                t.getCoefficient() >= 0 ? "+" : "", // Minus already there.
                t.getCoefficient(),
                t.getExponent()))
            .collect(Collectors.join(""))
            .replaceFirst("\\.x\\^0\\b", "")
            .replaceFirst("\\^1\\b", "");
    }
}
```